# How to attach proxy in AWS Lambda function for avoid '403 Forbidden error'?

Tags: proxy, scrapy, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, http-status-code-403

I'm making a scrapy crawler that parses site data and inserting it to dynamoDB through AWS Lambda Function

Sometimes it works fine - returning all data that i wanted with 200 status. And sometimes it wont crawling because of 403 (Forbidden) status.

I checked that on AWS Cloud9 the chance that an 403 Forbidden error will be less that on AWS Lambda: 100 function runs and only 3 Forbidden on AWS Cloud9, 100 function run and 78 Forbidden on AWS Lambda.
So i think i should try to do something with AWS Lambda network settings, like attach proxy or something else, but, how can i do it?

i'm already tried settings for crawler like:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3)    AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10',
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY':False,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': random.randint(1,10),
    'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': random.randint(80,150),
    'REDIRECT_ENABLED':False,
    'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
        'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware':True
    }
})
```

previously settings was:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
```

but it makes no difference: still works good on cloud9, sometimes(rarely) good on AWS Lambda

UPD: i found out that i getting 403 forbidden status in the daytime (from around 8:00 to 22:00) and in the nighttime i mostly get 200 ok status, so i think its because of site permissions to allowing and dissalowing robots in different periods of the day, but why running same script via AWS cloud9 mostly works good even in the daytime, while AWS lambda mostly not?

pre-apologize for grammar

Comment: A proxy would make you have `403` all the time, not just in some random requests, is there a chance you're being throttled?

Comment: @yorodm being..what? i could not find any documentation of that 'Throttle' term in programming, can you explain it in two words? Thanks

Comment: a server might be actively denying you access due to many concurrent requests.

Comment: yes, i found out that server denying me in daytime, and allowing me in nighttime